# ¿Se puede asignar varias rutas de imagen en php?

Tags: php, laravel, aplicación-web

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor!.
Estoy revisando un código en laravel y tiene unas rutas de imágenes

```
@return string
public function getImageUrlAttribute()
{
    if (!empty($this->image)) {
        $image_url = asset('/uploads/img/' . rawurlencode($this->image));
    } else {
        $image_url = asset('/img/default.png');
    }
    return $image_url;
}
```

En la parte de '/uploads/img' me gustaria saber si se pueden agregar mas rutas a parte de esta

Comment: Hola, no es posible. Es igual que cuando lo haces en HTML, solo puedes poner una ruta o enlace de esa img.

Comment: Hay forma de poder obtener todas las imágenes dentro de esa carpeta, ya que tengo varias carpetas con varias categorías de productos dentro de elsta

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de extraer todas las imágenes desde assets() de una vez. Pero podrías crearte una función en tu controlador para tal fin, también podrías generarte una ruta y toda la lógica para esto, ya depende de ti, la complejidad que necesites.

Para extraer con una función de php, todos los ficheros que haya en assests, podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
$images = \File::allFiles(public_path('images'));
```

esa línea extraería todos los archivos de la carpeta iamges dentro de la carpeta public, eso estaría devolviendo un `array` con todos los elementos de la carpeta

con eso, podrías o bien recorrerlo o mandarlo a una vista:

```
return View('tuVista')->with(array('images'=>$images));
```

Y en la vista, podrías recorrer tu array `images` e ir extrayendo los datos necesarios:

por ejemplo:

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
                     <li style="width:80px;display:inline-block;margin:5px 0px">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="{{$image->getFilename()}}"/>
                         <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}" width="50" height="50">
                     </li>
@endforeach
```

aquí se crea un foreach de `images` y creamos una lista con todos los nombres de las imágenes dentro de un input y además una imagen por cada vuelta que hace el foreach.

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado